# Recursion works weirdly with React

Tags: reactjs, recursion

I am trying to create a visualization of **Head Recursion** with React but the code works weirdly here.
With **Tail Recursion** the behaviour is as expected but with head recursion, it goes beyond the recursive call and prints the numbers bottom to top but bottom one getting printed first. ( tried using setState for printing with delay.) Following is the code for the same.

```
import React from 'react'

const Box = (props) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)
    var n = props.num
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //     setLoading(false)
    // }, 1000)

    // if (loading) {
    //     return <h1></h1>
    // }

    return (
        <div style={{
            marginLeft: n * 40,
            marginTop: 40
        }}>
            {n > 0 ? <> <Box num={n - 1} /> {console.log(`Called with n = ${n}`)} <div style={{
                width: 300,
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
                border: '1px solid black'
            }}>
                <h1>{n}</h1>
                <h1>fun({n - 1})</h1>
            </div>
            </> : null}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Box
```

When executed, the **console.log(`Called with n = ${n}`)** gets called immediately after recursive call to Box with n-1. ( I guess that this should not happen as it should complete the recursive call and then it should console log with values getting logged in reversed manner). I am calling the component with n = 5. Can anyone please explain what is wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `fun()`?

Comment: fun() is just for printing purpose, it has nothing to do with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the JS that your JSX is transformed into  [babel's site](https://babeljs.io/repl), (which is what the browser actually executes).

For your component it becomes something like this,

```js
import React from 'react';

const Box = props => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  var n = props.num; // setTimeout(() => {
  //     setLoading(false)
  // }, 1000)
  // if (loading) {
  //     return <h1></h1>
  // }

  return React.createElement("div", {
    style: {
      marginLeft: n * 40,
      marginTop: 40
    }
  }, n > 0 ? React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, " ", React.createElement(Box, {
    num: n - 1
  }), " ", console.log(`Called with n = ${n}`), " ", React.createElement("div", {
    style: {
      width: 300,
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
      border: '1px solid black'
    }
  }, React.createElement("h1", null, n), React.createElement("h1", null, "fun(", n - 1, ")"))) : null);
};

export default Box;
```

Looking at this you can see that the `console.log` is called and the return value is passed to `React.CreateElement` i.e. the `console.log` happens before the recursive call, that's why you are seeing the log go from n=5 to n=1.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. The printing of values is also from 5 to 1 with each box getting created from bottom to top. So is this code actually achieving Head Recursion or am I doing something wrong because in case of Tail recursion the boxes get created from top to bottom which is what I want.